# Using a widget with buttons to set device volume on Android, easy question...?

Tags: java, android, widget, android-intent, volume

I am simply trying to make a widget with a + button, a - Button, and a progress bar.  The bar should show the current volume and the plus and minus buttons should control the phone volume.  Right now I am just trying to get the plus button to do its function (the progress bar already shows the right volume when the widget is initiated)  but whenever I click the button I get a force close.  I've done apps before but never widgets, and I haven't worked with intents much.  Here is the code to the only class my Widget has:

```
package com.habosa.volumeslider;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class VolumeWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
    private AudioManager volume;
    private int whichStream = AudioManager.STREAM_RING;


public void goRinger() {
    whichStream = AudioManager.STREAM_RING;
}

public void goMedia() {
    whichStream = AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC;
}
public void goAlarm() {
    whichStream = AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM;
}
public void goNotification() {
    whichStream = AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION;
}

public void volumeUp() {
    volume.adjustStreamVolume(whichStream, AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, 0);
}

public void volumeDown() {
    volume.adjustStreamVolume(whichStream, AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER, 0);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    volume = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int maxVol = volume.getStreamMaxVolume(whichStream);
    int currentVol = volume.getStreamVolume(whichStream);
    RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    remoteView.setProgressBar(R.id.ProgressBar01, maxVol, currentVol, false);

    Intent plus = new Intent(context, VolumeWidgetProvider.class);
    plus.putExtra("msg", "plus");
    plus.setAction("BUTTONPRESS");

    PendingIntent plusPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, plus, 0);

    remoteView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.PlusButton, plusPendingIntent);

    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteView);
    }
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("BUTTONPRESS")) {
            String msg = "null";
            try {
                msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.e("Error", "msg = null");
            }

            if (msg.equals("plus")) {volumeUp();}

            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
        } else {
            // do nothing
        }

        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

and here is my manifest if that is relevant:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<receiver android:name="VolumeWidgetProvider" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    <action android:name="com.habosa.volumeslider.VolumeWidgetProvider.BUTTONPRESS"/>
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/volumewidgetproviderinfo" />
</receiver>

</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/tree/master/34-AdvAppWidget for a decent example to follow.

Note that the solution probably won't be to invoke the app widget provider class from the Intent, as you're apparently trying to do currently.

Comment: I just want the buttons I made to call the methods in my class, there has to be an easy way to do this without going through so many hoops, right?

Comment: Nope.  Not with app widgets.  The hoops are required.  And there's more!  http://blog.elsdoerfer.name/2009/06/03/writing-an-android-widget-what-the-docs-dont-tell-you/